# Problema en JavaScript botones que decrecen su valor en 1 cada vez que ponemos puntero encima (mouseover)

Tags: javascript, html, html5, onmouseover

Tengo un ejercicio que en cada clase se complica mas, esta vez se nos pide que de una serie de "n" botones, cada vez que el puntero pase por encima se le reste 1 hasta quedar en cero.
En cualquier momento se puede hacer "click" sobre ellos y restituir su valor inicial de 10.
He aplicado mis exiguos conocimientos y retomado el ejercicio cada día, pero no consigo pasar de este punto: *consigo que al hacer "click" sobre ellos se restituya su valor inicial de 10 pero no que cada vez que pase el puntero por encima ese valor decrezca en 1 hasta 0.*

Alguien que me eche una mano y me ayude a pasar de este punto? Prometo estudiar a fondo todas las soluciones posibles.
GRACIAS.

He aquí el código que he modificado una y mil veces probándolo todo:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ej06</title>
</head>
<body onmouseover="escucha_eve()">

    <h3>COMMIT 2023_04_21_0940</h3>

    <button id="btn_1" onclick="pone_diez()"></button>
    <button id="btn_2" onclick="pone_diez()"></button>
    <button id="btn_3" onclick="pone_diez()"></button><br>
    <button id="btn_4" onclick="pone_diez()"></button>
    <button id="btn_5" onclick="pone_diez()"></button>
    <button id="btn_6" onclick="pone_diez()"></button><br>
    <button id="btn_7" onclick="pone_diez()"></button>
    <button id="btn_8" onclick="pone_diez()"></button>
    <button id="btn_9" onclick="pone_diez()"></button><br>
          
    <script>
        let var_btn_1 = 10;
        let var_btn_2 = 10;
        let var_btn_3 = 10;
        let var_btn_4 = 10;
        let var_btn_5 = 10;
        let var_btn_6 = 10;
        let var_btn_7 = 10;
        let var_btn_8 = 10;
        let var_btn_9 = 10;

        btn_1.innerHTML = var_btn_1;
        btn_2.innerHTML = var_btn_2;
        btn_3.innerHTML = var_btn_3;
        btn_4.innerHTML = var_btn_4;
        btn_5.innerHTML = var_btn_5;
        btn_6.innerHTML = var_btn_6;
        btn_7.innerHTML = var_btn_7;
        btn_8.innerHTML = var_btn_8;
        btn_9.innerHTML = var_btn_9;
        
        function escucha_eve() {
            let btn_a = document.activeElement;

            btn_a.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction());
            btn_a.addEventListener("click", pone_diez);
        }
          
        function myFunction() {
            if (btn_a.innerHTML > 0) {
                btn_a.innerHTML = btn_a.innerHTML-1;     
            }
        }
        function pone_diez() {
            btn_a.innerHTML = 10;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocurre que si ejecutas la función `pone_diez()`, ocurre para todos tus botones.

A cada función del botón le podemos asignar el parámetro `this` para referenciar que el método ocurrirá únicamente para ese botón.

Es decir, si tenemos esto:

```
<button id="btn_1" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
```

El método `myFunction()` y `pone_diez()` ocurrirá sólo para ese elemento.

Optimizando un poco el código, podemos hacer algo como esto:

```js
function myFunction(btn_a) {
  if (btn_a.innerHTML > 0) {
    btn_a.innerHTML = btn_a.innerHTML-1;     
  }
}

function pone_diez(btn_a) {
  btn_a.innerHTML = 10;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_1" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
<button id="btn_2" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
<button id="btn_3" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button><br>
<button id="btn_4" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
<button id="btn_5" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
<button id="btn_6" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button><br>
<button id="btn_7" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
<button id="btn_8" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button>
<button id="btn_9" onmouseover="myFunction(this)" onclick="pone_diez(this)">10</button><br>
```

En donde ambas funciones operan directamente sobre el elemento `btn_a`, que es el botón en particular quien ingresará a esos métodos.

Comment: Funciona estupendamente!
Muchísimas GRACIAS